# Ionic 4: Is there a way to send data out of app

Tags: angular, ionic4

I currently have pages in my app displaying data like email address, phone number and physical address. I would like to make these to be sent out of app on button click. For example, when I click an email address on the page, I would like this to be sent to the email app on the phone that the user most uses, and preferably give him all the options at their disposal. So basically I would like a user to click that email in app, and then a popup window opens with all the email apps (Gmail, Outlook.. etc) that they can send that address to. Similarly for physical address, I want the user to click it and then all the options in which to open this are displayed (Apple Maps, Google Maps, etc). For phone number there seems to be the call number plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number), but I would like something even more general where if I clicked the number I could also send it to Facetime if I wanted. Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular anchor links like `<a href="mailto:email" target="_blank">email</a>`

Use `tel:` for phone numbers.

Target blank is so that it opens in a new tab, although that wouldn't really be relevant in Ionic as it sends it over to the OS regardless.